PREEMPT_RT patch for 5.15.163 linux kernel(5.15.0-1063-raspi) on Ubuntu 22
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 server on my CM4 and see that the Linux kernel it is running is 5.15.163. The rasberrypi/linux repository seems to have a much older kernel. I am trying to apply the PREEMPT_RT patch on this, but since the kernel on the repository and the kernel I am currently running don't match, the patch fails.
Is there a way to get the source code for Raspberry Pi supported 5.15.163 Linux kernel? If not what are my options to apply the PREEMPT_RT patch? I want to avoid upgrading to Ubuntu 24 or downgrading the kernel to the version on the repository.
